sourcing setup.bash takes time for source install of ros2 humble
I'm working with an Nvidia Jetson Xavier AGX running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (focal) (GNU/Linux 5.10.104-tegra aarch64).
Since ROS2 Humble binaries aren't available for Ubuntu 20.04, I had to build it from source following the instructions on the official ROS documentation page: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html.
Now, sourcing these built ROS2 binaries takes around 3 seconds, which is already too slow and not acceptable for efficient workflow.
Further, since binaries for standard community-contributed ROS2 humble packages are not available for Ubuntu 20.04, I created an overlay workspace. However, sourcing this overlay workspace is painfully slow, taking around 5+ seconds everytime.
The situation becomes even worse when adding an my working overlay workspace on top this.
Even tab completions don't work instantly, which is really frustrating when I'm trying to be productive.
I've been stuck on this performance issue for a while now, and it's starting to drive me crazy. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

It might not be related to your setup, but rather an issue in general.
There seems to be a related question, Sourcing setup in ROS2 slow (which doesn't appear to have either been, or survived, the migration over to here).
This question shows similar timings to those that you mention:

$ time source /home/art/ros2_ws/install/setup.bash
real    0m6.734s
user    0m5.344s
sys 0m0.340s


You might want to set the env vars AMENT_TRACE_SETUP_FILES=1 and  COLCON_TRACE=1 to see which files are being sourced.
There was a related Github issue, Sourcing setup.bash on ROS2 takes considerably longer compared to ROS1 #573, that has been closed.
From a linked Github issue, Sourcing setup script from Debian takes considerably longer than the local_setup script #929, this post suggests this as a workaround (with a x5 speed increase):

This is just proposal and experimental, but we can make it faster with file based _cached_ordered_commands


thanks for workaround. However, i am looking for more of a solution. This solution will cause the pain of rewriting the setup.bash/local_setup.bash for my workspaces every time i rebuild it.
